# Ollydbg doesn't separate memory section

Tags: assembly, memory, portable-executable, ollydbg

So I was casually hacking Minesweeper. I created a new section in PE file for my injected code, but as you can see in the following screenshot, ollydbg merged all original sections from PE file into one entry (.text, .data, .rsrc, .hack). This is very inconvenient. How do i split them so it will be more convenient for me to navigate?[image]

Comment: Just below the selection, you can see PE sections and their base addresses. If you double click one of the items then the corresponding disassembled code will be shown

Comment: My Olly 2.01 separates the sections for the 32-bit Minesweeper (Win7 RTM); go see if you have similar results with the original unhacked version; if you modified all of the sections to be code, Olly will likely merge them all upon load when consecutive.  Also look at the log when the PE file loads.  Olly will indicate when it merges sections together.

Comment: @byteptr the problem is i am using the old Windows XP version of minesweeper. Maybe the old executable is causing my issue

Comment: @Eugen1344, when I try this on XP SP3, I get the same results.  Run Olly on the original winmine.exe and you'll see.  Olly is combining the sections of your hacked version of winmine.exe because all of the sections have been modified to have the same R/W/E attributes.  Using a PE dumping program and have a look.  I don't think there is a way to prevent Olly from combining "like" sections